How do I change the framebuffer resolution at runtime without legacy /dev/fb0?
I have a server in production which was booted with a 1080p widescreen monitor attached and it used that when it automatically selected that resolution for the console on boot. Currently, it is attached with a standard 1280x1024-capable monitor, but it did not change the resolution to match so long lines go off the edges of the screen. How do I have it redetect the monitor or manually switch the resolution without requiring a reboot of this production server?
The console is only needed for certain maintenance and other core operations and we have been able to get by without seeing everything we are typing, but I would like to see if I can fix this sooner than the next, scheduled reboot of the server. Most answers seem to discuss using the obsolete fbset command, but their package was dropped from Fedora about 5 years ago and their official website is defunct now. Also, it looks like CONFIG_FB_DEVICE was not defined in the standard Fedora kernel so there's no /dev/fb* interface to even talk to. What is the current method to change the resolution used by the Linux framebuffer console?
I did see some mentions of KMS (Kernel Mode Setting), but no way to use that from the command-line. Also, I did confirm that running startx loads the correct resolution while inside X11, but I would prefer not to keep that running for the time being.

You're still using a framebuffer device if you see the kernel console (vtcon) because that console just doesn't support any other means of video output. What framebuffer driver do you use?

This would be using nvidiafb.
